# C++ STL for_each should take pointer to member function taking one argument

Tags: c++, stl

I have to pass the address of a member fn  taking one argument to the std::for_each. how do i do this?

```
class A{

void load()
{
vector<int> vt(10,20);
std::for_each(vt.begin(), vt.end(), &A::print); 
//It didnt work when i tried mem_fun1(&A::print)
}

void print(int a)
{
cout<<a;
}

};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using std::mem_fun, you have to pass pointer to class as first argument. You can bind it in this case with std::bind1st.

```
class A
{
public:
    void print(int v) {std::cout << v;}

    void load()
    {   
        std::vector<int> vt(10, 20);

        std::for_each(vt.begin(), vt.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::print), this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is, mem_fun would be to apply it on A instances, but vt contains `int`s as pointed by AraK.

Comment: @Matthieu: No, `mem_fun` turns the method into a binary functor. bind1st takes a binary functor and turns it into a unary functor. In this case the `mem_fun` arguments are `A*` and `int`; binding `this` as the first argument leaves a unary functor taking an `int` as intended.

Answer (score 4):

What you have in `vt` are integers not objects of type `A`. Also, `print` doesn't manipulate any of the member variables, just make it `static`:

```
class A{

void load()
{
vector<int> vt(10,20);
std::for_each(vt.begin(), vt.end(), A::print); // static functions are regular functions
}

static void print(int a)
{
cout<<a;
}

};
```

Answer (score 3):

I find boost::bind helpful.  That way I don't have to remember all the rules associated with std::mem_fun.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
class A{

void load()
{
  vector<int> vt(10,20);
  std::for_each(vt.begin(), vt.end(), boost::bind(&A::print,this,_1)); 
}

void print(int a)
{
  cout<<a;
}   
};
```

Though in this particular case, I would prefer the copy to [ostream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ostream_iterator/) idiom:

```
copy(vt.begin(), vt.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```